# Localization of Martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, local-martingales

by the definition of localization of martingale, one require for a sequence of stopping time $\tau_n\to \infty$ the $$1_{\tau_n>0}X_{\min\{t,\tau_n\}}$$ to be a martingale.

My question is:

1. Why it is necessary to multiply with the indicator function $1_{\tau_n>0}$ in the definition.
2. Why do I require $\tau_n\to \infty$ for $n\to \infty$?

Comment: For 1, I think [*this note*](http://math.bu.edu/people/prakashb/Math/stochint.pdf) gives an explanation.

Comment: I guess the author forgot to use $|X_0|$ instead.

Comment: @SangchulLee The semicolon should be interpreted as "conditioned on"? But I still cannot recognize why the inequality should hold. It still envolve $E[X_0]$

Comment: The notation $\Bbb{E}[X ; E]$ usually means $\Bbb{E}[X \mathbf{1}_E]$. So it is different from conditioning.

Comment: @SangchulLee But I still require $X_0$ to be integrable on the set ${T>0}$, I still cannot abandon the integrability of $X_0$ completely, didn't I?

Comment: Now all that the definition requires is that $X_0 \mathbf{1}_{\{ \tau_n > 0 \}}$ is integrable for each $n$. Of course this is still a restriction, but often  it is weaker than asking the integrability of $X_0$ itself.

Comment: @SangchulLee  Got it! Thanks.

Comment: No problem, good luck on your studying!

Comment: It is no restriction at all, in the following sense. Consider a constant process $X_t=X_0$ for all $t>0$, a.s. No assumption is made concerning the integrability of $X_0$. Define $\tau_n=\infty$ on $\{|X_0|\le n\}$ and $\tau_n=0$ on $\{|X_0|>n\}$. Clearly $1_{\{\tau_n>0\}}X_0$ is integrable, and the sequence $\{\tau_n\}$ localizes $(X_t)$, which is indeed (a most trivial) continuous local martingale.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thank you! Very intuitive example.